# Graph lines do not show dashes

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, numerical-integration, approximation

I have the following code of an iteration:

```
T[x_] := T[x] = (x/2)
x[0] = 7.9;
x[n_] := x[n] = T[x[n - 1]]
NumberForm[a1 = {Table[{x[i], x[i + 1]}, {i, 0, 9}]}, 9]
plot1 = ListPlot[a1, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashing[0.1]}]
```

When I run the above code, I have a straight-line graph with no dashes. When I remove `Red` from the `PlotStyle`, I get a dashed graph with different color, but I need a dashed graph with red coloring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "Directive[Red,Dashing[0.05]]:

```
plot1 = ListPlot[a1, Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Dashing[0.05]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Huber, I got what I need. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @JunaidAhmad - Alternatively, you could use `PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashing[0.1]}}`